# Edit contents of Setting File (settings.settings) in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, settings.settings

I am trying to display the contents of setting.setting file in DataGridView.

I have been successful in doing so by binding the data using BindingSource as follows

```
        BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();
        bindingSource1.DataSource = Properties.user.Default.Properties;
        settingsDataGridView.DataSource = bindingSource1;
```

Using this code, my DataGridView gets populated with the default values as below

[image]

`Setting Name` is read only.
`Settings Value` is editable.

I have provided a `Save` button on the form which has following code in
   the `OnClick` event

```
Properties.user.Default.Save();
```

The idea is to give control to the user to change the settings using a simple interface.

Unfortunately,this does not do the trick. `Save` button does not change the values in `settings.settings` file and the modified data does not persists between the application runs.

My Questions:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How can I get this thing working?

Guys any help is really appreciated.

Comment: have you marked the settings as user settings and not app settings?

Comment: @HeribertoLugo: yes it is "User" settings

Comment: User scoped settings are not stored in the settings file that you see in the application folder, though it is odd that you complain that the settings are not preserved between app runs. Did you try to Build and run your app in release mode outside of the debugging environment and see if the result is different? I.e. Don't click Play in visual studio, build the app and then double click on the exe like a user would, change some settings and restart the app by double clicking, like a user would

Comment: Off-topic, but use `PropertyGrid` instead.

Comment: @CaiusJard: Just now, tried running the application (release build) by double clicking it, but no luck. It is not preserving the values.

Comment: @RezaAghaei: logically speaking, I feel that I will face same issue in `PropertyGrid`

Comment: That's why I said my comment is *off-topic*. It's just a UI enhancement for your application :)

Answer (score 1):

If using a PropertyGrid is fine also:

1. Add a PropertyGrid from the toolbox to the form
2. Double click the form to create the Form_Load event
3. Add `propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = Properties.Settings.Default;
        propertyGrid1.BrowsableAttributes = new AttributeCollection(new UserScopedSettingAttribute());`
4. Click on the PropertyGrid and create the PropertyValueChanged event
5. Add `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();`
6. Play around with Designer to style the PropertyGrid e.g. Dock, PropertySort, HelpVisible, ToolbarVisible

Code should look similar to this:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace YourAppNamespace
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = Properties.Settings.Default;
            propertyGrid1.BrowsableAttributes = new AttributeCollection(new UserScopedSettingAttribute());
        }

        private void propertyGrid1_PropertyValueChanged(object s, PropertyValueChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

If the Settings file contains settings with Scope "User" then they should be displayed and saved if changed.